# Why dependencies of ubuntu-restricted-extras result non automatic?

Tags: package-management

I am trying to write down a small script, whose aim is to print out a list of packages I have installed explicitly.

So I take the packages installed **after** the end of installation, and in the state **not automatic**, but, between the others, `ubuntu-restricted-extras` shows this strange, in my opinion, behavior.

**Edit**: changed title from "automatic" to "non automatic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a meta-package. That will cause any installed direct dependencies of it be marked as not automatically. A meta-package can be removed afterwards, which is often mentioned in a packages description.

Comment: Sorry, I mean they are NOT marked automatic, my title was incorrect, i edited it.

Comment: Oops, I mixed meta-packages with traditional packages+dependencies. Meta-packages are special packages, and identified by `Section: metapackages` in the "control" file (found in control.tar.gz)